# HTML, SCSS, JSX , React, flexible gird

Tags: html, reactjs, sass, responsive-design, grid

[image]

I need this approach using a flexible gird approach where the user at 768px and 1024px media screen should be able to view the exact output as here, and on mobile application viewport it should be on a column approach derive this code using jsx and scss code. Thank you

I tried using grid approach but using translate and transform i obtained the positions but it wasn't effective like i have redo the whole code for separately for 712px and 768px this is bit terrible in obtaining the actual output as it is.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether you use flex or grid.
For responsive design, you should use one of the following methods.

- Use **media-query** that is a CSS technique introduced in CSS3 and change
  CSS properties on each resolution.
  The details of this technique introduced on [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)
- Considering that you mentioned **JSX**, you can design the component for
  various devices and render the corresponding component by recognizing
  the screen size of the user. You can use innerWidth to get the width of the user's screen.

  ```
  window.innerWidth
  ```

Another implementation approach is "Mobile-First". As a result, your entire layout will be rendered for desktop but in larger sizes. Keep in mind that you should avoid using pixels or any fixed values.

Comment: Thank you, but i have used this approach in obtaining the responsiveness i need the entire layout structure to be build as per the requirements

Comment: I would recommend you using `Mobile-First` design to perform this task.